# can you select a php imported html element with java script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, include, getelementsbyclassname

1. i am currently trying to add a class to a html element that is imported by php.The php file contains a a tag element

```
<a class="felt" href="felt.php">Felt Products</a>
```

i can not see the class being added, why is this? can js not effect imported elements?

```
<?php include 'headtaglinks.html'; ?>  
<script>
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("felt");
 element.classList.add("my-class");
</script>
```

2. if i am being able to add a class to a php imported html element, will the added class stay when clicking on a href link? or will the class stay and be written unless i remove it?

Comment: The browser doesn't know or care whether the HTML is static or came from PHP. It works the same.

Comment: How are you checking if the class was added? You need to use the Elements tab, not View Source.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements. This will work: `element[0].classList.add("my-class");`

Comment: For question #2... The browser will navigate to `felt.php`. So, the class won't stay, like the rest of the page anyway.

Comment: thankyou Louys Patrice Bessette! the issue seemed to be because i forgot the [0].

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array.

You need to modify your code to access the first element of the array or use another selector function like `querySelector('.felt')`

```html
<script>
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("felt")[0];
 element.classList.add("my-class");
</script>
```

```html
<script>
 var element = document.querySelector(".felt");
 element.classList.add("my-class");
</script>
```